# I need an example showing how to read and write a file, including a path to the Android internal storage

Tags: android, android-file

I'm tired messing around.
And i'm beginning to believe that it actually isn't possible.
Where do i find a simple example showing how to write a file "myPath/myFile.txt"?
And then reading it back again?

This an example of a code block that i can't get to work:

```
if(pathExists(path, ctx))  
{  
File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() +"/" + path, fileName);  
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);  

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);  

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();  
IOUtils.copy(fIn, writer, "UTF-8");  
fileStr = writer.toString();  
}
```

This is the error that i get:
"java.io.IOException: Is a directory"

Comment: Use this help link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: read this blog [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/read-file-from-internal-storage-via.html)

Answer (score 3):

This following snippet will copy you files which are saved in the application space to your desired path.

```
File mfile=new File("/data/data/src.com.file.example/files");
File[] list=mfile.listFiles();
    // The path where you like to save your files
String extStorageDirectory = "/mnt/sdcard/backup/";


    File file23 = null;
    File fr = null;
    for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++){
File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory +list[i].getName().substring(0,5));

if(myNewFolder.exists()){

   String selectedFilePathq = "data/data/src.com.file.example/file/"+list[i].getName();
file23 = new File(selectedFilePathq);
fr = new File(myNewFolder+"/"+list[i].getName());
}else{
  myNewFolder.mkdir();
String selectedFilePathq = "data/data/src.com.file.example/files  /"+list[i].getName();
file23 = new File(selectedFilePathq);
fr = new File(myNewFolder+"/"+list[i].getName());
}



try {
 copy(file23,fr);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}








public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: I was in need of a function that would write to the internal storage not the external directory.
The solution is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276745/is-it-possible-to-create-and-maintain-a-folder-structure-with-files-using-the-in/9279350#9279350
But i will keep you example in mind when i need to write the external directory.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could not write to Android internal storage (not unless your device is rooted) aside from the private file space assigned to your own application by the android system.

Comment: _aside from the private file space assigned to your own application by the android system._  
I'm writing to the private file space.  
That is what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Can't get that to work either :((

This an example of a code block that i can't get to work:  

    if(pathExists(path, ctx))  
    {  
    File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() +"/" + path, fileName);  
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);  
    
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);  
    
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();  
    IOUtils.copy(fIn, writer, "UTF-8");  
    fileStr = writer.toString();  
    }


This is the error that i get:  
"java.io.IOException: Is a directory"

Answer (score 0):

```
String strfile1 = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/serstatus.txt" ;

File f1 = new File(strfile1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use serialization methods as in java.
to save an text as file you should be using FileOutputStream and to read the file you should be using FileInputStream. You can check the following code it has a simple edittext and two buttons one to save and one to read data saved in that file.

The following code is to save text in the file named raksi.

```
Button savebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
savebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        e= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(e.getText().toString());
        String s = sb.toString();
        try { 
            final String TESTSTRING = new String(s);
            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("raksi.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            osw.write(TESTSTRING);
            ll = TESTSTRING.length();
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
});
```

The following code is the click listener for the button get. it reads the data from the file and displays as toast,

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("name.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[ll];
        isr.read(inputBuffer);
        String readString = new String(inputBuffer);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), readString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
    // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: This example doesn't seem to handle paths. Ex. "folder1/folder2/name.txt"